# dummy variable creation SparkR using "ml_create_dummy_variables"

Tags: r, sparkr, dummy-variable

I want to create dummy variable for a column of a Spark Dataframe in R. I am using **"ml_create_dummy_variables"** function to do so (have installed an older version of sparklyr for this). My data is already a spark dataframe. How do I apply "ml_create_dummy_variables" function to it.

Below is a similar example:

```
df <- createDataFrame(cbind(model = rownames(mtcars), mtcars))
tmp <- ml_create_dummy_variables(x=df,'Model', reference = NULL)
```

The documentation shows that your x should be **"An object coercable to a Spark DataFrame (typically, a tbl_spark)"**. But I want to apply this on a spark dataframe.